# Version JS files in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have react-app which created react-create-app. In my public/index.html i have some js file that js file too in my public folder. I wan't to give it version with date like

```
a.js?v=20191101
```

how i can do that?

Comment: You can just rename the file, are you trying add date dynamically?

Comment: yes i want to add date dynamically off course

Comment: You could use webpack to do that like we do for for hashed js and css, you could add you our version using webpack.

Comment: First, I understand that you are using create-react-app, so you are not writing your own webpack config file, this may not be easy but you may have to eject webpack which also has it own pros and cons. This is the closet one I can suggest [check this](https://hackernoon.com/webpack-creating-dynamically-named-outputs-for-wildcarded-entry-files-9241f596b065)

Comment: @MSoheb yes i already ejected webpack config file but there is where and what to do

Comment: so in the webpack.config.js you need to update in this way output: {
   filename: "[name].[hash].js",
   chunkFilename: "[name].[hash].js"
}, and after updating the file do npm run build and check

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS i have webpack.config.js and webpackDevServer.config.js files not prod i think i need to use first one. it's matter that my js file in public folder ? already there somethings like: isEnvProduction &&
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
          // both options are optional
          filename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
          chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
        }),

Comment: let me check it

Comment: Okey i'm waiting thank you

Comment: Before .js you can add the year, tried it working.

Answer (score 0):

So update the below things as follow, then you will be able to add an year to the chunk and minified js file

1. npm run eject
2. Inside config folder open webpack.config.js
3. Update the below properties in the file as your required, here its appending an year only

```js
output: {
  filename: isEnvProduction ?
    `static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].${new Date().getFullYear()}.js` :
    isEnvDevelopment && `static/js/bundle.js`,
  chunkFilename: isEnvProduction ?
    `static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].${new Date().getFullYear()}.chunk.js` :
    isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
}
```

4. After saving the file, npm run build